# How to compare Date in LINQ(Likewise Like in SQL query)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datetime

Is there any way to get `Date` only from `DateTime.Now` and that too will be of type `DateTime`.Because in my DB i have `CreatedDate` property which is of type`DateTime` .

```
var cmd = _ut.GetRepoInstance<Feedback>().GetAllRecords().Where(x => x.IsStatus == true & x.CreatedDate== DateTime.Now).Count();
```

Can someone suggest Linq query which will compare only Date part in between `DateTime.Now`from C# and `DateTime` type from Sql

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Date` gives the `Date` part right??

Comment: I am assuming you are querying the database via linqtosql and i have used DbFunctions for the same . var cmd = _ut.GetRepoInstance<Feedback>().GetAllRecords().Where(x => x.IsStatus == true & DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CreatedDate)== DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now)).Count();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cmd = _ut.GetRepoInstance<Feedback>().GetAllRecords().Where(x => x.IsStatus == true & x.CreatedDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).Count();
```

Comment: It will give value like `06/15/2016 12:00:00 AM` but i want to compare `06/15/2016` of `DateTime.Now.Date` to `06/15/2016 04:30:00 AM`(Only `06/15/2016`) of `DateTime` in Sql

Comment: Thanks mate..please ignore my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

`Date` property on `DateTime.Now` gives you the `Date` value and time part will be `00:00:00` which is even of `DateTime` datatype.

So your query is

```
var cmd = _ut.GetRepoInstance<Feedback>().GetAllRecords().Where(x => x.IsStatus == true & x.CreatedDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).Count();
```

Comment: Thank you for your input :)